# How to store data to MySQL for array input

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, normalization

Hope my question is correct to the post.

```
  <form action="process.php?id=<?php echo intval($order['id']);?>" method="post">
  <ul>
  <?php
  $sd = 'SELECT * FROM download WHERE pid IN ('.$order['pid'].') ORDER BY pid ASC'; // pid IN (3,4,5)
  $qd = $db->rq($sd);
  $no = 1; while($download = $db->fetch($qd)) {
  ?>
  <li>
  <?php echo $no; ?> <?php echo $download['title']; ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="mid[]" value="<?php echo $order['mid']; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="pid[]" value="<?php echo $download['pid']; ?>" />
  </li>
  <?php $no++; } ?>
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> 
  </form>
```

**Output**

1. Sony Ericsson Drivers
2. Sony Ericsson Apps
3. Samsung Drivers
4. Motorola Drivers

**Question**

1. How to store (save) the data `Output` to table structure at below on `process.php`
2. Data will be save something like these.

   ```
   id | mid | pid | title
   -----------------------------------------
   1  |  1  |  3  |  Sony Erricson Drivers
   -----------------------------------------
   2  |  1  |  3  |  Sony Erricson Apps
   -----------------------------------------
   3  |  1  |  4  |  Samsung Drivers
   -----------------------------------------
   4  |  1  |  5  |  Motorola Drivers  
   -----------------------------------------
   ```

**process.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) {
// I'm blur how to get dynamic mid[] & pid[] here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a third hidden field for titles eg:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="title[]" value="<?php echo $download['title']; ?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="mid[]" value="<?php echo $order['mid']; ?>" />
 <input type="hidden" name="pid[]" value="<?php echo $download['pid']; ?>" />
```

Now you can store it like this, suppose your page gets submitted to `process.php`, this is what you should put in there:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  for($i = 0; $i<=count($_POST['title']); $i++)
  {
     $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title'][$i]);
     $mid = intval($_POST['mid'][$i]);
     $pid = intval($_POST['pid'][$i]);

     // database code
     $query = "insert into table set title = '$title', mid = $mid, pid = $pid";
     // mysql_query and/or more code....
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and explanation. It's working great. Just one question, when data stored to db had empty `mid pid title` on the `last id` of auto increment

Comment: @kampit: Can't say, you should check your code, know how many things are coming up in those arrays.

Comment: Ok fixed. I changed the `for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['title']);)` and put the `$i++;` before the last }

Comment: @kampit: That is good to know, i was about to write that now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do a loop over the $_POST['mid'] and the $_POST['pid'] array, like this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($_POST['mid']); $i++)
{
  $mid = $_POST['mid'][$i];
  $pid = $_POST['pid'][$i];
}
```

If you want to pass the item's name too you can just pass it the same way you sent 'mid' and 'pid' fields.

Answer (score 0):

You get the values for `mid[]` and `pid[]` the same way you're checking `submit`, by accessing the `POST` variables:

```
$mid = $_POST['mid'];
$pid = $_POST['pid'];
```

Since they're posted as arrays, they'll be arrays in the `$_POST` variable. You can also check the structure of the individual $_POST variables or the entire $_POST variable by the following:

```
var_dump($_POST['mid']);
var_dump($_POST);
```

This is a useful function for debugging or figuring out a variable whose contents you're unsure about.